# Rspec Test Failing Says flash message not present when it is

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have a form that is submtted using ajax.

This all works.

Here is the controller:

```
 def create_bp
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        flash[:success] = "Your friend's details have been saved."
         #format.html { render :template => 'pages/home'}
         format.js   { render :action => "success" }
      else
        format.html { render :template => 'pages/home'}
        format.js   { render :action => "failure" }
      end
    end
  end
```

Here is the user_controller_spec test:

```
   it "should show the correct flash message" do
            xhr :post, :create_bp, :user => @attr
            flash[:success].should =~ /Your friend's details have been saved./i
          end
```

Here is the message given by the test when it fails:

```
  1) UsersController Ajax 'create_bp' success should show the correct flash message
     Failure/Error: flash[:success].should =~ /Your friend's details have been saved./i
       expected: /Your friend's details have been saved./i
            got: nil (using =~)
     # ./spec/controllers/user_controller_spec.rb:77:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

The flash message is being created and I can see it on the page as well.
```

Why does it say it got nil if I am setting the flash[:success] right there in the controller?

Comment: Are you sure `@user.save` is returning true? Maybe validation is failing.

Comment: Not sure, but since you are testing your controller, is this a situation where you'd want to add render_views?  See:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027518/what-does-render-views-do-in-rspec  Another option would be to test for this sort of higher level behavior with capybara and cucumber IMHO.

Comment: Check whether save did worked before checking for message. This will make you're live easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try use **flash.now[:success]** instead just **flash[:success]** for JS case.

```
def create_bp
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      flash.now[:success] = "Your friend's details have been saved."
      format.js   { render :action => "success" }
    else
      format.html { render :template => 'pages/home'}
      format.js   { render :action => "failure" }
    end
  end
end
```