# What does render_views do in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm new to rspec and fairly new to rails. When writing test cases for controllers I've noticed `render_views` used often. **What does this do and what happens if I don't call it?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

it renders the view's in the controller spec. If you don't put render_views, the views won't render, that means the controller is called but after it returns the views are not rendered. Controller tests will run faster, as they won't have to render the view, but you might miss bugs in the view.

Comment: Ok makes sense. So if my controller doesn't have any associated views then calling `render_views` is pointless? My tests work fine w/o calling `render_views` so I guess that's the case.

Answer (score 9):

It's about [isolation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-rails/file/README.md#Controller_Specs). The idea is that you don't want your controller specs failing because there is a syntax error in the view, which should cause a request spec or a view spec to fail. If you're not writing request specs or view specs, or Cucumber features, then `render_views` can help you from a test-coverage perspective.

Comment: As you noted [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/rspec/Gwnlou54x1M), I will add that render_views can also be utilized in helper specs if, say, there is a helper that renders a partial or template.